# Unable to eliminate views inside a ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter, layout-inflater

I have a couple of problems with my `ListView`. I'll try to explain my problems first by explaining the aim of the `ListView`, and later step by step by showing some pieces of code and images. At the bottom of the page I have the whole code of the 3 classes related with the ListView.

This ListView is used to modify a sequence of bus stops. Each rows contains a `TextView` with the name of the bus stop and a `Button` to eliminate it. If the user taps on the `TextView`, this view is replaced with a new layout. In this new layout there is an `EditText` used to insert the name of a new bus stop that will be exchanged with the old one. Next to the `EditText` there is a button, used for completing the operation.

The problems:

- **first problem**: if I try to eliminate the original `TextView` from the UI, I eliminate also the rows under the one selected(from the UI). Here a couple of images.
  Before that I click:[image]

After that I click on a `TextView`:(there should be the last row, that contains Crocetta, but it has been deleted and I don't know when it happens and what is the cause of that)[image]

**UPDATE**: I forget to say that when you click the ok button, the `ListView` became as it is in the first image. i.e. I can see the elements that seemed to be eliminated.

The code that manages the replace of the view with the new layout is the following:

```
    ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) ((TextView)v).getParent();
    int index = parent.indexOfChild((TextView)v);   
    parent.removeView((TextView)v);

    final LinearLayout nuovoLiInserimento = (LinearLayout) li.inflate(R.layout.edit_text_modifica_fermata, parent, false);
    final AutoCompleteTextView nuovaFermata = (AutoCompleteTextView) nuovoLiInserimento.findViewById(R.id.edtModificaFermataInModificaLinea);
    Button confermaModificaFermata = (Button) nuovoLiInserimento.findViewById(R.id.btnModificaFermataInModificaLinea);
    nuovaFermata.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(context,android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, caricaFermate()));
    nuovaFermata.setText(fermataPrecedente);

    [...]

    parent.addView(nuovoLiInserimento, index);
```

- **second problem**: this happens when I click on the Elimina `Button`, whose purpose is to delete the row where it lies. I delete the data from `fermate`, the `ArrayList` that contains the data of the `ListView`, and I call `notifyDataSetChanged`. When the program later enters in `getView` , I get the following error:

  `05-03 19:26:12.684: E/AndroidRuntime(1818): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  05-03 19:26:12.684: E/AndroidRuntime(1818): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 3, size is 3`

Because `getView` is called one time more than the needed, so it searches the element in `fermate` that I deleted. How to avoid that?

Here is the piece of code:

```
private void eliminaFermata(View v){
    Toast.makeText(context, "elimina", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();       
    LinearLayout parent = (LinearLayout)((Button) v).getParent();
    TextView busStop = (TextView)(parent).findViewById(textViewDaCompletare);
    fermate.remove(fermate.indexOf(busStop.getText().toString()));
    this.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Eventually I post the code of 3 classes: the one that contains the `ListView`, the `ArrayAdapter` and the one that implements the `OnClickListener` of the `TextView`. Moreover I post the xml files that are been inflated in this classes.

**The class that contains the ListView**

```
    package fragments;

import [...]

public class FragmentModificaLinea extends Fragment {

private Button btnModificaLinea = null;
private Button btnConfermaModifica = null;
private AutoCompleteTextView edtModificaLinea = null;
private ArrayList<String> contenitoreLinee;
private ListView listView;
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private static final String TAG = FragmentModificaLinea.class.getSimpleName();


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_modifica_linea, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    btnModificaLinea = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.btnModificaLinea);
    edtModificaLinea = (AutoCompleteTextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.edtModificaLinea);
    contenitoreLinee = new ArrayList<String>();
    caricaLinee();
    edtModificaLinea.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, contenitoreLinee));
    listView = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.listViewModificaLinea);
    btnConfermaModifica = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.btnConfermaModifica);

    btnModificaLinea.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(!edtModificaLinea.getText().toString().matches(""))
                if(contenitoreLinee.contains(edtModificaLinea.getText().toString())){
                    listView.setAdapter(new AdapterModificaLinea(getActivity(), R.layout.elemento_modifica_linea,
                            R.id.txtCambiaFermata, caricaFermate(edtModificaLinea.getText().toString().split(" Cod: ")[1])));
                    listView.setVisibility(ListView.VISIBLE);
                }else Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Inserire una delle linee suggerite.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            else Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Inserire il nome della linea", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}

private void caricaLinee(){
    // I get the local database.
    DatabaseLocale db = new DatabaseLocale(getActivity());
    SQLiteDatabase dbLeggibile = db.getReadableDatabase();

    // Execute the query.
    Cursor cursore = dbLeggibile.rawQuery("SELECT " + DatabaseLocale.getTagNomeLinea() + " || ' Cod: ' || " + DatabaseLocale.getTagCodiceLinea()
            + " AS linea FROM " + DatabaseLocale.getTableNameLinea(), null);
    while(cursore.moveToNext()){
        contenitoreLinee.add(cursore.getString(0));
    }

    // Close connections.
    cursore.close();
    db.close();
}

private ArrayList<String> caricaFermate(String CodLinea){
    ArrayList<String> listaDelleFermate = new ArrayList<String>();

    // I get the local database.
    DatabaseLocale db = new DatabaseLocale(getActivity());
    SQLiteDatabase dbLeggibile = db.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor fermate = dbLeggibile.rawQuery("SELECT f." + DatabaseLocale.getTagNomeFermata() + 
            " FROM " + DatabaseLocale.getTableNameTratta() + " t JOIN " + DatabaseLocale.getTableNameFermata() + " f "
            + "ON f." + DatabaseLocale.getTagCodiceFermata() + " = t." + DatabaseLocale.getTagCodiceFermata()
            + " WHERE " + DatabaseLocale.getTagCodiceLinea() + " = '" + CodLinea + "'", null);

    while(fermate.moveToNext()){
        // Successiva - NomeFermata
        listaDelleFermate.add(fermate.getString(0));        
    }
    fermate.close();
    db.close();

    return listaDelleFermate;
}

}
```

**The class that extends the ArrayAdapter**

```
    package listViewModificaLinea;

import [...]

public class AdapterModificaLinea extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

Context context;
int layoutResourceId;   
int textViewDaCompletare;   
ArrayList<String> fermate = null;
private LayoutInflater li = null;

public AdapterModificaLinea(Context context, int resource,
        int textViewResourceId, List<String> objects) {
    super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, objects);
    this.context = context;
    layoutResourceId = resource;
    textViewDaCompletare = textViewResourceId;
    fermate = new ArrayList<String>(objects);   
    li = ((LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE));
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    TextView text = null;
    Button btn = null;
    if(convertView == null){
        convertView = li.inflate(layoutResourceId, null);
    }
    text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(textViewDaCompletare);
    // If I delete an element from fermate, it looks however for it and I get outofbound, why?
    String fermata = fermate.get(position);
    text.setText(fermata);
    // If I click on the textView, I exchange with the new layout
    text.setOnClickListener(new onClickListenerPerTextViewFermata(context, textViewDaCompletare));

    btn = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnEliminaFermataModificaLinea);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            eliminaFermata(v);
        }
    });

    return convertView;
}

private void eliminaFermata(View v){
    Toast.makeText(context, "elimina", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();       
    LinearLayout parent = (LinearLayout)((Button) v).getParent();
    TextView busStop = (TextView)(parent).findViewById(textViewDaCompletare);
    fermate.remove(fermate.indexOf(busStop.getText().toString()));
    this.notifyDataSetChanged();
}


}
```

**The class that implement OnClickListener**

```
    package listViewModificaLinea;

import [...]

public class onClickListenerPerTextViewFermata implements View.OnClickListener{

private Context context = null;
private LayoutInflater li = null;
private int textViewDaCompletare = 0;

public onClickListenerPerTextViewFermata(Context context, int textViewResourceId){
    this.context = context;
    li = ((LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE));
    this.textViewDaCompletare = textViewResourceId;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    String fermataPrecedente = ((TextView)v).getText().toString();  
    ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) ((TextView)v).getParent(); // parent
    int index = parent.indexOfChild((TextView)v);       
    parent.removeView((TextView)v);  // I remove it

        // new layout
    final LinearLayout nuovoLiInserimento = (LinearLayout) li.inflate(R.layout.edit_text_modifica_fermata, parent, false);
    // AutoCompleteTextView and Button, I put the adapter for the AutoCompleteTextView
    final AutoCompleteTextView nuovaFermata = (AutoCompleteTextView) nuovoLiInserimento.findViewById(R.id.edtModificaFermataInModificaLinea);
    Button confermaModificaFermata = (Button) nuovoLiInserimento.findViewById(R.id.btnModificaFermataInModificaLinea);
    nuovaFermata.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(context,android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, caricaFermate()));
    nuovaFermata.setText(fermataPrecedente);

    // click listener al bottone
    confermaModificaFermata.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            // text of AutoCompleteTextView
            String fermata = nuovaFermata.getText().toString();
            // layout edit_text_modifica_fermata, later layout inside the listview              ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup)(((Button)v).getParent()).getParent();
            int index = parent.indexOfChild(nuovoLiInserimento);
            parent.removeView(nuovoLiInserimento);
            TextView fermataCambiata = new TextView(context);
            fermataCambiata.setText(fermata);
            fermataCambiata.setId(textViewDaCompletare);
                        // i  add this OnClickListener
            fermataCambiata.setOnClickListener(new onClickListenerPerTextViewFermata(context,  textViewDaCompletare));
            parent.addView(fermataCambiata, index);
        }
    });

    // aggiungo il nuovo layout al parent
    parent.addView(nuovoLiInserimento, index);
}

private ArrayList<String> caricaFermate(){
    ArrayList<String> listaDelleFermate = new ArrayList<String>();

    DatabaseLocale db = new DatabaseLocale(context);
    SQLiteDatabase dbLeggibile = db.getReadableDatabase();

    // Tutte le fermate
    Cursor fermate = dbLeggibile.rawQuery("SELECT " + DatabaseLocale.getTagNomeFermata() + 
            " FROM " + DatabaseLocale.getTableNameFermata(), null);

    while(fermate.moveToNext()){
        listaDelleFermate.add(fermate.getString(0));        
    }
    fermate.close();
    db.close();

    return listaDelleFermate;
}

}
```

**elemento_modifica_linea.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtCambiaFermata"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnEliminaFermataModificaLinea"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/eliminaFermataInModificaLinea" />
```

**edit_text_modifica_fermata.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtCambiaFermata"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnEliminaFermataModificaLinea"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/eliminaFermataInModificaLinea" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I don't know what is the cause of my problems, can you help me?
Thank you very much!

Comment: can you change your button click code to btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            fermate.removeat(position);
    this.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
    });

Comment: The reason for the second problem is quite simple. In the adapter's constructor you create a **new** `ArrayList` containing the data items passed in while the adapter is based on the `objects` list reference that you pass in the constructor. When you delete an item, the item gets deleted from the new list `fermate` but the adapter still uses the `objects` list reference, so you get the `ArrayOutOfBounds` exception(because you get the data directly from the `fermate` list which is short by one element). I didn't understand the flow for the first problem, please expand on that in your question.

Answer (score 0):

**Regarding problem 2**

You better should extend from `BaseAdapter` instead of `ArrayAdapter`. There's a method named `getCount()` that returns the number of items and you'll have to implement it so that it returns `fermate.size()`.

I think that ArrayAdapter assumes the count from the array you pass initially and when you remove entries from the array the count is bigger than the number of items in the array, leading to the `OutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: I think you are right, but it possible to override method getCount of ArrayAdapter. ArrayAdapter simply extends BaseAdapter and there is no need to change adapter type.

Comment: I'm too, but in some case I'm using cursor adapter. But in this case it's enougth to override getCount().

Answer (score 0):

Ok, let's start with your second problem. Try to override getCount() method in your adapter. ListView calls getCount method in your adapter, and after that call getView() such times as getCount() returned. Try to add somthing like this in your adapter:

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return fermate.size();
}
```

What about second problem. I think remove and add views inside listView is not good idea. The better way is add EditText and TextView when you creating layout and set visibility of EditText as GONE. And on click simple change visibility of TextView and EditText. It will work faster and mmore easy.

Answer (score 0):

To delete a row, I will suggest that you send a broadcast from the adapter into activity and pass the index of row as an "extra". Then, you can delete it from your list adapter normally and reset the list view. Doing it inside the adapter may cause problems.